# how to get text from combobox like item [1]

Tags: c#, wpf, text, combobox, get

when i use this code  "var z = comboBox.Items[1].ToString();" and then show z in                         "MessageBox" i get this message "DataMdellayer.custumer" but i want text of item 1

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="57,63,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
```

and

```
comboBox.ItemsSource = database.Customers.ToList();
comboBox.DisplayMemberPath = "CustomerSay";
comboBox.SelectedValuePath = "CustomerID ";
```

Comment: You should not access the Items collection when you have assigned ItemsSource. Get the data from the source collection, i.e. `database.Customers`. That said, `((Customer)comboBox.Items[1]).CustomerSay` should work.

Comment: thanks bro it work

Answer (score 1):

You are using `CustomerSay` property of `Customers` to show the value.

When you say:

```
var z = comboBox.Items[1].ToString();
```

You are converting a `Costumer` to `string`

But, considering that you want that costumer's `CostumerSay` property, you have to look for it.

So you must cast your ComboBoxItem to Costumer

```
(Customer)comboBox.Items[1]
```

And then look for the property

```
var z = ((Customer)comboBox.Items[1]).CustomerSay
```

Answer (score 0):

1- You can cast your item to the data source object (customer) as @Marko said.

2- Use MVVM and bind your combobox to a ViewModel property. WPF has strong binding system to implement MVVM.

3- You can override ToString method of Customer class:

```
public class Customer
{
  public override string ToString()
  {
    return CustomerSay;
  }
}
```

I prefer the second solution, but if you don't want to use MVVM pattern @Marko's solution is better.

Answer (score -2):

The index of item one starts at zero in c# so change your code like below to get the item one

var z = comboBox.Items[0].ToString();

Comment: That doesn't answer the question, nor does it explain why they are receiving the object's type name or how to access the text they require.